# Iterate through different column index numbers in VLOOKUP

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am trying to write a macro that extracts data from a table using VLOOKUP, but for each column complete, I want to be able to increase the column index number to get the next lot of data. The macro looks like this so far:

```
Sub ExtractAddress()

Dim RowNum As Integer
RowNum = 2
Dim FinalRow As Integer
FinalRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Dim ColNum As Integer
ColNum = 10

    For RowNum = 2 To FinalRow
        For ColNum = 10 To 27
            Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, ColNum).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'[Address list.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R407C19,2,FALSE)"
        Next ColNum
    Next RowNum

End Sub
```

So for each loop through ColNum I want to increase the Column Index Number as well, otherwise I just end up with the same data in each column. I have tried using a variable J and increasing this after each cycle of the loop but it doesn't seem to accept this.

I am a learner with VBA so an answer in simple terms would be very helpful.

Thank you all!

Comment: Are you sure you want the `ColNum` to start at `10`? The range for vlookup also includes the columns 10-19, `Sheet1'!R1C1:R407C19`. Dont you mean `ColNum = 20 `?

Comment: Thank you for this, I did not know the correct notation to add ColNum to the formula. I will also try the tip you gave me to make it more simple. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

Try this. I just added the `ColNum` to the formula :

`Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(RowNum, ColNum).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'[Address list.xlsx]Sheet1'!R1C1:R407C19," & ColNum - 8 &",FALSE)"`

---

### Notes, a bit off topic :

You don't have to loop through all the cells one by one to apply formula, you can do this in less steps, with less ranges and an "universal formula", meaning correctly used relative and absolute references.

Something like this (this is by columns, I cannot think of a way to apply the formula to whole range at once)

```
Sub ExtractAddress()

    Dim RowNum As Integer
    Dim FinalRow As Integer
    Dim ColNum As Integer

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        FinalRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For ColNum = 20 To 27
                .Range(.Cells(2, ColNum), .Cells(FinalRow, ColNum)).FormulaR1C1 = _
                "=VLOOKUP(R[0]C1,R1C1:R" & FinalRow & "C19," & ColNum - 18 & "  ,FALSE)"
        Next ColNum
    End With

End Sub
```